# Divide list into groups by specific criteria

Tags: list, powershell

I have a list (csv) of over a thousand entries. 
It looks like this:

```
First Name  Surname  Gender  City    Birthdate   Age  Index
----------  -------  ------  ------  ----------  ---  -----
Sam         Smith    f       Munich  06.04.1999  17   1
```

Every entry represents one person. 
I want to divide them into groups with powershell.

There are several criteria that have to be met for each group:

- Each group should consist of 7 people max
- In every group there should be 2 to 3 persons from the same city
- Below the age of 18 they should be seperated by gender
- Above 18 there may be mixed groups

I don't need help with the powershell code, rather than with the logic behind it.
By now, I tried sorting them first by age, then by city and gender. But I still don't know how to group it with the right criteria.

Comment: For me it sounds more like TSQL Window Functions with partitioning and such. With Powershell you could probably do this step by step to fit your requirements. Neither way I dont think there will be easy way to perform such a complex groupping.

Comment: Do your own homework!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach to do this but I would use **backtracking** to solve it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

it's easy to explain.
It's like an bruteforce algorithm with intelligence.

**Basic how it works:**

1) Take one person in Group A
 1.1) Check condition (look below)
 1.2) If condtion are true => take next Person to Group A or when Group A is full take it into Group B.
   1.1.2) Check condition
   ... and so on
 1.3) if Condition are false => Go one step back and take another person. If there is no other person then go so long a step back until you can take another person. 
*(this is what is different then a simple Brute Force, because the algorithm know that this path won't lead to a solution so he won't look in it further.*

*Don't forget to form a new group when one group is full.*

**Conditions:**

2 to 3 persons from the same city
Below age 18 only men/women
*you only have to check the actual group because all groups before are okay since you don't modified them.*

**End**
As soon as every person is in a group and all condition are true you are finish.
Or when you tried each combination but nothing lead to an solution you are also finished => not solution possible

**Solution:**

When a solution exist it will find one.